# how to apply "wait" in my slide down effect?

Tags: jquery

how to apply wait function on effect for my slide down. 
my code is mention below but give me answer how do i wait to slide down effect

```
 var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(function()
      {
    j(document).ready(function(){
    j("#wrapper #headerSlots  #header-8  ul#globalNav  li.navigationGrop  a.mainNode").mouseenter(function(){
    j(this).next('ul.linkList.navigationLinks').slideDown(1000,'swing');


    /*j(this).next('ul.linkList.navigationLinks').animate({
    left: '+=0',
    height: 'toggle'
    }, 500, function() {
    // Animation complete. j(this).parent().next('.linkList navigationLinks')
    });*/

    });
    j("#wrapper #headerSlots  #header-8  ul#globalNav  li.navigationGrop").mouseleave(function(){
    j(this).children('ul.linkList.navigationLinks').slideUp('fast', 'swing', '');
       // j(this).next('ul.linkList.navigationLinks').slideUp('slow');
    });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.delay()` jQuery method to add hold effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.delay(time in milliseconds)` before calling the `slideUp()` method.

```
j(this).next('ul.linkList.navigationLinks').delay(1000).slideDown(1000,'swing');
```

Comment: i have use .delay(1000) in "amazon webstore" but its getting error like ".delay is not a method"

Comment: which version of jquery are you using

Comment: .delay() method is only present in jQuery V1.4 or greater